# Is there a possible way to fix the hover selector triggering over and under the text because of the height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in the CSS below, I have the height set to "50vh" which is causing the hover selector to be triggered underneath and over the text rather than just on the text. I have tried to lower the height but it moves the text upwards. Is there a way to stop it from triggering unless the cursor is over the actual text while still keeping the text lowered?

```css
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo h1 {
  align-items: center;
  color: #262626;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 50vh;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo h1:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>
    Bindex. | Home
  </title>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <body>

    <div class="logo">
      <h1>
        B.
      </h1>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use more elements? E.g., a wrapper that's 50vh and centers the `h1`.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to implement a wrapper right now.

Comment: By setting the height of H1 to something greater than the text needs, you added empty space around the text. If you hadn't specified a height on the same element that has the `:hover`, you wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: I had been messing around with different ways to center text vertically and horizontally and I used flex but it wouldn't work unless I specified the height. Unfortunately if I remove the height from it, it won't be dead centered. I used a wrapper instead and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. You should set the `flex` properties on the parent div only, and not the `h1`. This way, you can manipulate the height of the `h1` and the width in which the `:hover` is activated.

```css
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #262626;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.logo h1:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>
    Bindex. | Home
  </title>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="logo">
    <h1>
      B.
    </h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow can't believe I didn't even think of that. Thank you a lot for teaching me a new trick. I will definitely be using this later on throughout this project.